# Jquery plugin conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery plugins for sliding, toggle navigation and Collapsible toggle.

The problem is that, When I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My slider and toggle navigation works. but my collapsible toggle does not works.

The necessary plugin for collapsible toggle is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

but when I add this,it works and the other two stops working.

Please guide so that three of them works.

Comment: And what error do you get in console???

Comment: @A.Wolff:  I get error as `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: So now i have to ask wich line produces this error? Etc...  Usually, this is just bad idea to load two jquery versions on same page. Better would be to upgrade all plugins if possible

Comment: it is conflicting for the plugins,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it's position i.e. if you are adding it at the top then place it at the bottom of other one and use $.noConflict() at starting of  tag. This might solve your problem.

Comment: can you suggest how to use `$.noConflict()` ?

Comment: $.noConflict() or jQuery.noConflict() help in those situation where we are using $ and jQuery both, you are adding two different plugins and it might be possible that one of these is using $ and other one jQuery instead of $. It's true that both work in same manner but if both are used then a conflict can occur. Apart from it Change the positions also.

Comment: I did it my self and it worked.Thanks a lot to all..!!

Comment: You should really aim to only use 1 version of jQuery. 1 is big enough for your users to have to download. Also when jQuery upgrades sometimes core components are separated into separate plugins. E.g. jQuery UI. THAT could be the real reason things stopped working when you upgraded to 1.11.2.